# Reach this position in four moves

Tags: problems, retrograde-analysis

I recently came across this chess problem. The requirement is to reach this position (starting from a basic board set up board) in 4 moves. How do you do it?

```
[FEN "rnbqkbnr/pp3ppp/2p1p3/8/4P3/8/PPPP1PPP/RNBQK1NR w KQkq - 0 1"]
```

Comment: yeah it does. Btw, how do I create a stack exchange chessboard?

Answer (score 2):

> 1. e4 e6 2. Bb5 Ke7 3. Bxd7 c6 4. Be8 Kxe8